# How can I fixed Huawei Cloud DB error which is multi thread?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I used huawei cloud db in my project. I called creatobjecttype() and openclouddbzone() method in my first screen.I received a message that an error occurred in the app. I test my app on Cloud Debugging with the device which the problem is seen.(P30) I deleted all Cloud DB funcs in this screen and test again. App is not crashing now?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem. That was a kind of thread error because of Cloud DB post requests. I add this line in onCreate.

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call `creatobjecttype()` and `openclouddbzone()` *before* making any cloud DB query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the database migration tool [UGO](https://console-intl.huaweicloud.com/ugo/?agencyId=3e98e027aa1b488faa2f7d56de58d26d&region=ap-southeast-3&locale=en-us) to migrate your DB even with the schemas